# python element is no longer attached to the dom selenium

Tags: python, firefox, python-2.7, selenium

I get "element is no longer attached to the dom" exception even though the element is there and is clickable, I am trying to click the "next" arrow on ryanair website, the html for the next button is:

```
<li class="newer" ng-class="{'loadingsmall':loading}">
<a ng-disabled="loading" ng-click="loadMore(0, 'SelectInput$LinkButtonNext1', 1)"
title="Next Week" href="">
</a>
</li>
```

I located and clicked it in several methods:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//a[@title='Next Week']")))
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Next Week']")
elem.click()
```

and:

```
area = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Next Week']")
action = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(area) action.click(area) action.perform()
```

and:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('>')
elem.click()
```

all work fine if I have no action in between, but once I tell selenium to click on other elements on the page (I do not move to other pages, I stay on the same page and show some dynamic content) the "next" link only works the first time around, and then gives me the exceptions, help would be so greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're still on the same page but the DOM's elements have changed due to some AJAX actions & calls, so you're forced to re-detect your object using:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('>')
```

If you don't do that, it is more than likely that you'll get a

```
StaleReferenceException
```

For more [info](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=staleelementreferenceexception#selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException)